# How to build just git changed files in jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, ftp, publish

I've Just installed git and Jenkins.
then I use "Published over ftp" plugin at jenkins and I send files by ftp after builds. but all the files are sent at every build.
I'd like to send only last changed source files.
How can I send just changed files???

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you want to have a Jenkins pipeline checked in. Ideally, that pipeline would be in another repository. And ideally, the pipeline would checkout code afresh before each build. My suggestion is to get rid of file transfer plugins altogether.

If that’s not an immediate possibility, consider rsync. But please consider fixing your build workflow.

Comment: In short, "Published over ftp" plugin can not send only changed files.(everytime send all of it.).
But you mean that pipeline can do that?

Comment: No, I mean the rsync protocol can do that. I’m still suggesting you stay away from both ftp and rsync, and implement a Jenkins pipeline the way it’s supposed to be - using scm (source control management) for retrieving code.

Comment: Okay. Use the rsync fucntion. and implement a jenkins pipeline.Many thanks. Timir.